# Writting to a docx file from a txt file in python

Tags: python, utf-8, docx

I've been trying to make my python code to fill a form in word with data that i scraped off the Internet. I wrote the data in a txt file and are now trying to fill the word file with this code:

```
import zipfile
import os
import tempfile
import shutil
import codecs



def getXml(docxFilename,ReplaceText):
    zip = zipfile.ZipFile(open(docxFilename,"rb"))
    xmlString= zip.read("word/document.xml")
    for key in ReplaceText.keys():
        xmlString = xmlString.replace(str(key), str(ReplaceText.get(key)))
    return xmlString

def createNewDocx(originalDocx,xmlString,newFilename):
    tmpDir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
    zip = zipfile.ZipFile(open(originalDocx,"rb"))
    zip.extractall(tmpDir)
    #3tmpDir=tmpDir.decode("utf-8")
    with open(os.path.join(tmpDir,"word/document.xml"),"w") as f:
        f.write(xmlString)
    filenames = zip.namelist()
    zipCopyFilename = newFilename
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zipCopyFilename,"w") as docx:
        for filename in filenames:
            docx.write(os.path.join(tmpDir,filename),filename)
    shutil.rmtree(tmpDir)

f=open('test.txt', 'r',)
text=f.read().split("\n")
print text[1]
Pavarde = text[1]
Replace = {"PAVARDE1":Pavarde}
createNewDocx("test.docx",getXml("test.docx",Replace),"test2.docx")
```

The file is created but I cant open it.

I get the following error:

```
Illegal xlm character
```

My guess would be that theres something with the encoding but I cant find a solution.